# Using rownum in sub query on oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have query like this.It is working properly on oracle 12.

```
select * from customers where customerId IN (select custId from Orders where 
   orderStatus = 'S' and orderCity = 'Amsterdam' and ORDER BY custId DESC FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
```

But I am using oracle 11.That query is not working on oracle 11.Therefore I changed my query like that

```
select * from customers where customerId IN (select custId from Orders where 
  orderStatus = 'S' and orderCity = 'Amsterdam' and ORDER BY custId DESC rownum <= 10)
```

It gives `missing right paranthesis`

How can I solve this problem.Do you have any idea?Actually I use a variable instead on 10 number.

Comment: The code looks syntactically correct to me, although I would suggest an `order by`.

Comment: Please post **actual query**,as it is not reproducible at the moment [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7408ba1a8912e133306db082b5309c41)

Comment: You're missing an `AND` -- `WHERE ... AND rownum <= 10`...

Comment: Syntax is a bit different - you need an extra subquery so it would need to be more like where customerId IN (select * from (select custId from Orders where orderStatus = 'S' and orderCity = 'Amsterdam' and ORDER BY custId DESC) where rownum <=10)

Comment: So much nicer with 12 :-)

Comment: "and order by" is an invalid sequence of keywords.

Comment: Ah cool, I added it as an answer after double checking that I was right - my memory isn't as good as it used to be :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is a bit different - you need an extra subquery so it would need to be more like ...
`where customerId IN (select * from (select custId from Orders where orderStatus = 'S' and orderCity = 'Amsterdam' and ORDER BY custId DESC) where rownum <=10)`

You wouldn't need the extra subquery if you didn't have the order by clause

For ref see [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm#:~:text=For%20each%20row%20returned%20by,has%202%2C%20and%20so%20on](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm#:%7E:text=For%20each%20row%20returned%20by,has%202%2C%20and%20so%20on).

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this with `exists` and `row_number()`:

```
select c.* 
from customers 
where exists (
    select 1
    from (
        select custId, row_number() over(order by custid desc) rn
        from orders 
        where orderStatus = 'S' and orderCity = 'Amsterdam'
    ) o
    where o.rn <= 10 and o.cusid = c.customerid
)
```

`row_number()` ranks orders by descending customer id in the subquery. Then, we filter on the first 10 rows, and use `exists` to filter the corresponding rows in the outer query.